# Unexpected behaviour in rails when defining class_name in habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models (Course and Dancer). A course can have many dancers (students) and teachers (also dancers). Teachers can be students of other courses.

I define the tables as follows:

```
create_table "course_enrollments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer    "dancer_id",     :null => false
    t.integer    "course_id",     :null => false
    t.datetime "attended_on", :null => false
end

create_table "courses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string     "name",             :null => false
    t.string     "genre"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "courses_teachers", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "course_id",    :null => false
    t.integer "teacher_id", :null => false
end

create_table "dancers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string     "first_name", :null => false
    t.string     "last_name",    :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

And the classes:

```
class Dancer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :course_enrollments
    has_many :courses, :through => :course_enrollments
    has_many :teachers, :through => :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :course_enrollments
    has_many :dancers, :through => :course_enrollments
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, :class_name => 'Dancer'
end

class CourseEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :dancer
    belongs_to :course
end
```

Based on the guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), I would expect the teachers attribute of Course to look for the table courses_teachers and use teacher_id as the foreign key. Instead it's looking for courses_dancers and dancer_id, presumably from setting class_name to 'Dancer'. Is this by design or is it a bug? I can get it to work if I instead do:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, :class_name => 'Dancer', :join_table => :courses_teachers
```

And rename teacher_id to dancer_id in the courses_teachers table

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [api for habtm](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many), there's an option for `foreign_key` and `association_foreign_key`.  Try the following

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, :class_name => 'Dancer', :join_table => :courses_teachers, :foreign_key => :course_id, :association_foreign_key => :teacher_id
```

I'm not sure if it will work without passing `foreign_key` option but it probably will so try without it first.

Comment: That works (with/without foreign_key set). Am I alone in thinking though that "has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers" should look in courses_teachers and use teacher_id irregardless of whether class_name is specified or not? It seems like a lot to type for something that is so trivial/straightforward.

Comment: To me it seems that once you set `class_name`, the process for deriving the values of the `join_table` and `foreign_key` does become ambiguous. I do think the current behaviour seen here is sane, if that's worth anything.